# VSTO: Visual Studio 2005 with Office 2010 64

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, vsto, office-2010, office-2003

I was developing a Office 2003 Add-In with Visual Studio 2005. But after unistall Office 2003 and intall Office 2010 x64, my project stops working.

It's present some errors:

```
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'IRibbonControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    x.cs    83  45  x
Error   5   The type or namespace name 'IRibbonUI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) x.cs    358 38  x
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'IRibbonExtensibility' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Core' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  x.cs    45  43  x
```

There is some way to make my AddIn run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you have seen this or not, but here's some of the explanations:

> Office 2010 32-bit should run VSTO 2005 SE add-ins without
>   modifications, but Office 2010 64-bit will not load VSTO 2005 SE
>   add-ins.
>
> Office solutions that require the Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office
>   Second Edition Runtime are not compatible with 64-bit versions of
>   Microsoft Office 2010. To run these solutions in the 64-bit edition of
>   Microsoft Office 2010, you must upgrade the project to Visual Studio
>   2010 or to a Visual Studio 2008 project that targets the 2007
>   Microsoft Office system.

More details [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/921dfc91-b076-4c11-87c9-2e1a79e7c260/).

Also check out VSTO compatibility table on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSTO) which might be useful info

Comment: Hi woodykiddy ı tired your solution. I upgrade my project to vs2010 and setup again yes My add-in works on 64 bit office. But If I use same setup for office 2003 it is not working. I want to use one setup for office 2007-2010 and 2003. Is this possible?